# IMG tag SRC attribute with URL encoding

Tags: html, amazon-s3

I'm trying so show an image from a public read bucket on S3:

The image is not found when the source is encoded like with `%3F`:

```
<img src="https://mybucket$$$.s3.amazonaws.com/images/my-image.jpg%3F12345"></img>
```

When I unescape `%3F` to `?` I can find the file:

```
<img src="https://mybucket$$$.s3.amazonaws.com/images/my-image.jpg?12345"></img>
```

**Is there a way to use the encoded URL or I really need to unescape the URL?**

Comment: `%3f` and `?` have completely different meanings in a URL. Those two URLs are _not the same_, they are different URLs. So the answer to your question: Of course you need to use the _right_ URL, and not a different one.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong here, but as the `?` symbol denotes a query string in the ASCII character set there should be no reason to encode it.